# Identify UUID of HC-06

Tags: bluetooth

I'm currently learning about using BLE with Arduino and iOS. From what I understand (correct me if I'm mistaken), each type of BT device has a UUID. I'm using a HC-06 module connected to my Arduino. How do I find out what the UUID of a HC-06 is? I've been looking through data sheets to no avail.

Comment: Voting to close: this is a question about the HC-06 or iOS development, *not* about Arduino.  That said, you might want to see what a BTLE scanner program like "light blue" or similar can find.

Answer (score 3):

In Android, I used this UUID to connect to HC-06,

```
  socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

  inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
  outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
```

You can use this UUID in your Android code, But over iOS, I think the Bluetooth is really a completely different hardware specs.

Hope I helped

Comment: Android use the SPP protocol as the HC-05 and HC-06, but it seems iOS don't. So comunicating with an iOS machine would be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Well guess what, HC-06 is not low energy so no iOS device will ever see that module despite whatever uUid you have, so go and get a bluetooth 4.0 aka BLE module